# Tabla factura en sistema de diferentes tipos de facturas

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

Buenas me pregunto como podría crear la tabla factura y detalle de factura en un sistema donde no solo se venden artículos. La cuestión es la siguiente en un negocio hay un restaurante y además venden artículos o productos entonces como podría estructurar la base de datos para que pueda tener facturas de articulos o del servicio de comida en una sola tabla.
He pensado en hacer diferentes tablas de factura una para cada tipo de factura o hacer que la tabla de factura contenga artículos o el pedido del servicio de restaurante y que esos campos sean nulleables y segun el tipo de factura paso el id de alguno de ellos.

En realidad no se cual seria la forma correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Excelente pregunta en cuestiones de diseño siempre vas a encontrar muchas opiniones desde mi punto de vista hay dos soluciones, ver los servicios de comida como un ítem más lo cual es muy usado, creando el ítem “menú del día “ o “menú especial “ , y en otra tabla incluir el inventario de los productos usados para la preparación de los menús, cosa que te permita cruzar los costos de producción con las ganancias adquiridas

Comment: en realidad la pregunta es de baja calidad puesto que depende del escenario o lógica de negocio que intente resolver, por lo mismo se va a prestar a interpretaciones, por otro lado preguntas asi de amplias no deben ser respondidas en tanto no sean dudas claras, por otro lado te pido revises [answer] pues tu publicación parece mas un comentario que respuesta

Comment: El escenario esta mencionado en la pregunta un negocio que brinda servicios de comida y vende productos.